# Azure Redis cache console returns error for any command

Tags: azure, redis

I am using a Redis cache with a c# client. My app is deployed on Azure, but it is not able to connect to the server. When trying to write any command in the Azure portal's Redis console, I get "**error**" back.
[image]

Does anyone know what is the issue here?

Comment: but I have another redis cache for my demo website and it is working. it has the same settings.

Comment: what should be done in that case?

Comment: I am ran into the same issue and found that the port used to communicate to the Redis Console is not the standard Http 80 port.  My problem ended up being a firewall issue as the company I work for blocks pretty much everything.  Trying from my home network was successful.

Comment: Any solution to this problem? Any new redis cache that I create in the West Europe DS has this exact issue.

Comment: The issue resolved itself after some time. It was a problem in Azure's side.

Comment: I have met the same problem.There are maybe some problems in Azure side and it worked well two days later.